# Reading a text file and ignoring commented lines in C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm currently working on making a tiny computer in C for a programming assignment and I'm stuck on one part.

I'm stuck on how to correctly ignore comments in a text file that I'm reading in. (Example of file input below).

```
Input File
5 5     //IN 5
6 7     //OUT 7
3 0     //STORE 0
5 5     //IN 5
6 7     //OUT 7
3 1     //STORE 1
1 0     //LOAD 0
4 1     //SUB 1
3 0     //STORE 0
6 7     //OUT 7
1 1     //LOAD 1
6 7     //OUT 7
7 0     //END
```

The first input on each new line is an operation, the 2nd input being an address. I am planning to have a switch statement for each op and then calling the appropriate function.  This is my current layout for reading in the file:

```
//file handling
int c;
FILE * file;
file = fopen(name, "r");
if (file){
    printf("Run.\n");
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
        op = c;
        switch (op){
            case 5:
                print("Inside case 5\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

How can I ignore the // on each line and skip to the next line in the file?

Comment: `c = getc(file)` won't do what you want. Either call `strtol` (but this would require having an actual C string to pass) or change `case 5:` to `case '5':` - but that won't work for two-digit numbers.

Comment: my guess is, you are going to have to do multiple reads for each line.  First, you read for the operation.  Second, you're going to read a space (ignored), followed by an address.  Lastly, you'll read (in a loop, probably) a bunch of spaces and other non relevant characters that will be ignored, looking for a `\n` (newline).  Once the newline is found, then you start the process over on the next line.  Note that this entire process is **extremely dependent on the file remaining this same structure.**

Comment: One way would be to read whole lines using `fgets`, then call `strstr` to look for the `//`, and if you find it, overwrite the first character with `'\0'` (that is, modifying your input line buffer) to truncate the string before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to correctly ignore comments in a text file that I'm reading in
>   How can I ignore the // on each line and skip to the next line in the file?

Read the *line* using `fgets()`

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file)) {
```

Look for the `//` with `strstr()` [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885621/reading-a-text-file-and-ignoring-commented-lines-in-c#comment86788006_49885621) and lop off the string at that point.

```
  char *slash_slash = strstr(buf, "//");
  if (slash_slash) {
    *slash_slash = '\0';
  }
```

Continue processing the line as desired.

```
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call fgets to get a full line:

```
fgets(buffer, 100, file);
```

and then extract the two numbers from the line:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d%d", &instruction, &address);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `fgets` and `strtok` you can read line by line and split the string acording to the `//` delimiter. Here's an example (it is not fully checked, but it's the main idea):

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (f== NULL)
    {
        printf("opening file failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[256] = { 0 };
    while (fgets(buf, 256, f))
    {
        char *s = strtok(buf, "//");
        if (s == NULL)
        {
            printf("s == NULL\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", s);
        }
        memset(buf, 0, 256);
    }
    fclose(f);
```

**EDIT:** I just realized that this is not exactly what you were looking for. However, you can still use it in order to first ignore the comment, and then break the given string into operation and address, or whatever that is...

Comment: `strtok(buf, "//");` will perform like `strtok(buf, "/");`